# Sphinx Search ERROR: unknown key name 'SELECT'

Tags: sphinx

My query contains backslashes.  Not sure how to escape them...

```
sql_query = \
            SELECT t.id, \
                   t.title, \ 
                    preg_replace('#\\[(c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|ab)([^\\]]*)\\]([^\\[]+)\\[/\\1\\]#siU' , '', \  
                          (SELECT group_concat(p2.content, ' ') \
                          FROM   content_table p2  \
                          WHERE  p2.id = t.id))        AS content, \
            FROM   my_table t \
            \
```

My server has lib_mysqludf_preg installed.

Answer (score 0):

This message `unknown key name` is often because you have a space after the eol `\` on the line before.

If you copy/pasted the above snippet, it appears that might be the case on the preg_replace line.

Comment: While my code pasted in stackoverflow does seem to have a space after the \; it does not have it in my source.